# Uploading multiple files using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

Is there any way to do this ? I mean to upload multiple files in to files folder ?

At the moment I have this, But here I can upload only one File, :

[image]

But what I want to do is this (If u click this little +, then coming new input, where u can choose another file.) :

[image]

**Uploadfile VIEW Code**

```
<div class="users view">
<h2><?php echo __('Lisa Fail'); ?></h2>
    <?php
echo $this->Form->create('uploadFile', array( 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('pdf_path', array('type' => 'file','label' => ''));
//echo $this->Form->input('files.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));
echo $this->Form->end('Upload file');
$image_src = $this->webroot.'files/'.$image;
```

**Uploadfile CONTROLLER Code**

```
public function uploadFile() {
            $filename = '';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values
        $uploadData = $this->data['uploadFile']['pdf_path'];
                if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) { // checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                    return false;
                }
                $filename = basename($uploadData['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = time() .'_'. $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                    return false;
                } 

            }
           $this->set('image',$filename); 

    }
```

I have one Javascript, maybe I can use this , or not (What this is doing?: Its doing same thing, but its doing number input, where u can type a number) ?

```
var lastRow=0;
function addNumber() { 
$("#mytable tbody>tr#number0").clone(true).attr('id','lisanumbrid'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr#trAdd"); 
$("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeNumber('+lastRow+')'); 
$("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('numbrid','data[Lisanumbrid]['+lastRow+'][lisanumbrid]').attr({'id':'numbridlisaNumber'+lastRow,'name': 'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid]['+ lastRow +']'}); 
lastRow++; 
}
    function removeNumber(x) {
        $("#lisanumbrid"+x).remove();
    }
```

and in view file I have this, to use this js:

```
<table id="mytable">
        <tr id="number0" style="display:none;">
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this number')); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid', array ('name'=>'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid][0]')) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another number','onclick'=>'addNumber()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('addNumber');
```

Can somebody help me and give some clue or solution, Is that possible to use this Javascript ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Now I have this javascript, and missing is only : how to upload these files in to FILES folder now ? This Controller dont work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append new input field with it's name containing `[]` or `[some_array_key]`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $(".files").append("<input type='file' name='files[]'/><br/>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="files">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" /><br/>
</div>
<button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
```

Comment: and in to controller I need to put something like this ? `foreach($this->request->data['files'] as $file){
                            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $uuid . '.jpg');
                }`

Comment: Okay, this script works correctly, I mark this answer useful, but I cant accept the answer, because its doing nothing. I need to upload  these files in to webroot/files, and its not working, If I click Submit, its doing nothing .

Comment: @frantsium When you will submit your form, all input fields will be submitted. My answer is for your question `But what I want to do is this (If u click this little +, then coming new input, where u can choose another file.)`

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. I didnt ask how to upload these files in to webroot/files